# Why Redux-Saga is reseting state in my React Native application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I have a saga watcher like:

```
export default function * root () {
  yield all([
    takeLatest(HoraBusaoTypes.GET_HORA_BUSAO, getHorasBusao)
  ])
}
```

So I'm `put` a data to redux store in this saga like:

```
export function * getHorasBusao(action) {
  yield put({ type: HoraBusaoTypes.TEST, nome: 'New York' });
}
```

And I have a reducer (I'm using `reduxsauce`):

```
export const test = (state, action) => {
  const { nome } = action;
  return { ...state, nome };
};

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [Types.TEST]: test
})
```

So I dispatch that action in the `componentDidMount`:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getHoras('Any city')
  }
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// redux map
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { horaBusao } = state;
  return {
    nome: horaBusao.nome
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getHoras: (city) => dispatch({ type: 'GET_HORA_BUSAO', city })
  }
}
```

But it's not displaying the data to the page, so I added a `console.warn` into `render` function, and I figured out that data has been set and reset:

[image: Android emulator screenshot with console.warn error message]

Which part of the code is reseting my redux store?